# How to upgrade PrimeFaces 3.5 to 8.0

Tags: jsf, primefaces, upgrade

I have to upgrade PrimeFaces version to 8.0. Current version is 3.5. I don't know how to begin.

Answer (score 7):

We have a MigrationGuide in our PrimeFaces Docs: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/../migrationguide/migrationguide.

We had it in our Wiki before: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide

Comment: link is now dead and must be replaced by https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/../migrationguide/migrationguide

Answer (score -1):

Depends how your project is structured.

If the project has enough UI testing, you might get away with incremental updates. Step-by-Step. Otherwise you might have to write some tests before updating anything. Simply because:

**Each update will break some existing functionality**

My suggestion would be to **completely forget** about primefaces and decouple the UI from Java entirely by re-implement it in React, Vue or any decent frontend solution. All you have to do it to expose a bunch of endpoints from your Java application for the frontend to communicate with.

Good Luck bro with your journey.